# Select join with identation

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, join

I have two Tables on my tsql server

```
Table 1: Car {id, name}
Table 1: CarPart {id, name, CarId}
```

I want my select result to appear similiar to the following format

```
id  -  carname   -  carpartId   -  carPartName
----------------------------------------------- 
1        car1
                       101          CarPartA
                       102          CarPartV
                       103          CarPartFD
2        car2
                       101          CarPartAA
                       102          CarPartDD
                       103          CarPartD1
3        car3
                       101          CarPartCA
                       102          CarPart1D
                       103          CarPartDB
```

Is it possible to display this with identation in one single select?
Thanks.

Comment: A query normally has no _identation_, that's work for the client, for example the control that consumes and displays  this data.

Comment: SQL is a language to get data.. this seems like a native UI operation.

Comment: Your cars all have the same ID.

Comment: Try using the report designer in visual studio instead. Or use visual studio (or other IDE's) to write to a text box/console.

Comment: It's possible to do in SQL, but it almost certainly will be hard to work with on client side. If you still need it and nobody will create it, I'll check this question in an hour and create it for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost never a good idea. Whatever you are using to execute SQL is almost certainly better suited for modifying how your data gets presented.

That said, there are a few useful cases where the presentation layer is rubbish, and for those cases, it could make sense. I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that you're dealing with one of those cases.

```
select id = presentationid, carname, carpartid, carpartname
from (
select carid = id, presentationid = id, carname = name, carpartid = null, carpartname = null
from Car
union all
select carid = Car.id, presentationid = null, carname = null, carpartid = CarPart.id, carpartname = CarPart.Name
from Car
inner join CarPart
on CarPart.CarId = Car.id
) as sub
order by carid, carpartid;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6a57e/2

Since you want separate rows for the car data and for the car part data, you need to combine the results of two separate `select` bits, and order them in such a way that the car part data follows the corresponding car data. I'm doing this by adding `carid` to the list, which gets filled even for the car part data.

Comment: Actually it's always a bad idea, but sometimes a bad idea is the only one which will work in time. :(

Comment: That was very enlightening. I dont need it for production. For log viewing and debugging it is a great solution.Thanks.